# Evaluating strings in Julia_Eval for diffeqr solver

Tags: r, julia, eval, differential-equations

I am trying to evaluate strings within a for loop within an R script using `JuliaCall::julia_eval`. While I was able to accomplish this in R using the `deSolve` package, I am running into issues when converting the code to one that is compatible with Julia. The base code for the correctly functioning R deSolve code is shown below.

```
library(deSolve)
library(dplyr)

 Combine <- c(" - 1*0.4545*(H2O2^1) - 1*27000000*(`$OH`^1)*(H2O2^1)", " - 1*3100000000*(`1,4-dioxane`^1)*(`$OH`^1)", 
    " - 1*33000*(TOC^1)*(`$OH`^1)", "2*0.4545*(H2O2^1) - 1*3100000000*(`1,4-dioxane`^1)*(`$OH`^1) - 1*33000*(TOC^1)*(`$OH`^1) - 1*27000000*(`$OH`^1)*(H2O2^1) - 1*8500000*(`$OH`^1)*(`HCO3-`^1) - 1*390000000*(`$OH`^1)*(`CO3 2-`^1)", 
    " - 1*8500000*(`$OH`^1)*(`HCO3-`^1)", " - 1*390000000*(`$OH`^1)*(`CO3 2-`^1)"
    )

time <- seq(from=0, to=0.01, by = 1E-4)
State <- c(H2O2 = 0.000294117647058824, `1,4-dioxane` = 0.00000113494, 
TOC = 0, `$OH` = 0, `HCO3-` = 0.003766104, `CO3 2-` = 0.0000167638711956647)

ODEcreater2 <- function(t, state, parameters){
  with(as.list(c(state)),{
           for (i in 1:6) { #
            dY[i] <- eval(parse(text=Combine[i]))}
      return(list(dY))
} )}

out1<- ode(y = state, times = time, func = ODEcreater2, parms = NULL)
```

I am trying to use replicate the code and run it in Julia to improve the speed of the ODE solver by using `diffeqr` vs. `deSolve`. Unfortunately, I am running into evaluating the string/expression within a for loop in `julia_call`.

```
library(diffeqr)
diffeqr::diffeq_setup()
library(JuliaCall)
julia <- julia_setup()

    ODEcreater <- JuliaCall::julia_eval("
    function (dY,t,state)
        for i in 1:6
          dY[i] = eval(Meta.parse(:Combine[i]))
    end
    end")

    tspan <- list(1E-6, 1E-3)

    sol = diffeqr::ode.solve(ODEcreater,state,tspan, abstol=1e-8, reltol=1e-8)
```

Does anyone have any insight into the best way to evaluate the strings within the for loop? I have been investigating metaexpressions on the JuliaLang website but am still lost.

Comment: You don't need to or want to build a function that uses eval and Meta.parse at all. Just build the string you want to use.

Comment: Thanks Chris! Are you saying I can just leave it as a string in Julia_eval? so that I would have `dY[i] = Combine[i]`?

Comment: Yes, just build a string.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the duplicate question https://stackoverflow.com/a/58766919/1544203 , building the string and then doing

```
sprintf("function f(du,u,p,t)\n%s\nend", paste(Combine, collapse="\n"))
```

from the R side builds a single string which matches the format that works. This is also optimal since it excludes any extra function calls from the generated function.

Answer (score -1):

from [julia docs](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Base.Meta.parse-Tuple%7BAbstractString%7D):

```
parse(str; raise=true, depwarn=true)

Parse the expression string greedily, returning a single expression. An error is thrown if there are additional
  characters after the first expression. If raise is true (default), syntax errors will raise an error; otherwise, parse
  will return an expression that will raise an error upon evaluation. If depwarn is false, deprecation warnings will be
  suppressed.

  julia> Meta.parse("x = 3")
  :(x = 3)
```

so, `Meta.parse` accepts a string and returns an expression. this should evaluate correctly:

```
eval(Meta.parse(Combine[i]))
```

one problem i see is the use of non-valid julia variable names, like `$OH`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I agree I am having issues with the syntax. Even if I simplify the first expression without a forloop and the full expression:
`du[1] = eval(- 1*0.4545*(H2O2^1) - 1*27000000*(`$OH`^1)*(H2O2^1))`
it doesnt seem to work.

Comment: what if you reformulate from a list (tuple? i don't know a lot of R) to a vector?

Comment: can you try change combine to:
`c(" - 1*0.4545*state[1] - 1*27000000*state[4]*state[1]", 
" - 1*3100000000*(state[2])*(state[4])", 
" - 1*33000*(state[3])*(state[4])", "2*0.4545*(state[1]) - 1*3100000000*(state[2])*(state[4]) - 1*33000*(state[3])*(state[4]) - 1*27000000*(state[4])*(state[1]) - 1*8500000*(state[4])*(state[5]) - 1*390000000*(state[4])*(state[6])", 
" - 1*8500000*(state[4])*(state[5])", " - 1*390000000*(state[4])*(state[6])"
)` ; and state to `c(0.000294117647058824,0.00000113494,0,0,0.003766104,0.0000167638711956647)` ??