# Generate DifferentialEquations ifrom a vector in Julia

Tags: r, julia, ode, differential-equations

I have created a vector which concatenates strings of differential equations that are in the correct format to be used be the differeq ode sovler in Julia (i.e, f(du,u,p,t):

```
Combine <- c("du[1] = - 1*0.4545*(u[1]^1) - 1*27000000*(u[4]^1)*(u[1]^1)", 
"du[2] = - 1*3100000000*(u[2]^1)*(u[4]^1)", "du[3] = - 1*33000*(u[3]^1)*(u[4]^1)", 
"du[4] =2*0.4545*(u[1]^1) - 1*3100000000*(u[2]^1)*(u[4]^1) - 1*33000*(u[3]^1)*(u[4]^1) - 1*27000000*(u[4]^1)*(u[1]^1) - 1*8500000*(u[4]^1)*(u[5]^1) - 1*390000000*(u[4]^1)*(u[6]^1)", 
"du[5] = - 1*8500000*(u[4]^1)*(u[5]^1)", "du[6] = - 1*390000000*(u[4]^1)*(u[6]^1)"
```

My question is how can I evaluate these expressions using JuliaCall:Julia_eval? I know that if I explicitly include the expressions the ODE solver works correctly, but if I just use Combine[i] I run into an error because I am calling a global variable.

```
f <- JuliaCall::julia_eval("
     function f(du,u,p,t)
                                  du[1] = - 1*0.4545*(u[1]^1) - 1*27000000*(u[4]^1)*(u[1]^1)
                                  du[2] = - 1*3100000000*(u[2]^1)*(u[4]^1)
                                  du[3] = - 1*33000*(u[3]^1)*(u[4]^1)
                                  du[4] = 2*0.4545*(u[1]^1) - 1*3100000000*(u[2]^1)*(u[4]^1) - 1*33000*(u[3]^1)*(u[4]^1) - 1*27000000*(u[4]^1)*(u[1]^1) - 1*8500000*(u[4]^1)*(u[5]^1) - 1*390000000*(u[4]^1)*(u[6]^1)
                                  du[5] = - 1*8500000*(u[4]^1)*(u[5]^1)
                                  du[6] = - 1*390000000*(u[4]^1)*(u[6]^1)
end")
```

Is there any way to work around this? I have tried unlisting "Combine" and creating a single string with \n included at the end of each line but this was unsuccessful. It would be ideal if I could call in the vector from the global environment and have that analyzed by the ODE solver, something like below ( i know this cant work like this):

```
f <- JuliaCall::julia_eval("
     function f(du,u,p,t)
         Combine[i]
end")
```

Comment: Just interpolate the strings into the string.

Comment: Hey Chris, could you explain this in more detail. While I can make a compiled string using paste and/or sprintf, how exactly would I call this into the juli_eval function? For example, lets say I create `"du[1] = - 1*0.4545*(u[1]^1) - 1*27000000*(u[4]^1)*(u[1]^1)+\n du[2] = - 1*3100000000*(u[2]^1)*(u[4]^1)+\n ..."` then what do I do? Just a bit lost here man

Comment: `sprintf("function f(du,u,p,t)\n%s\nend", paste(Combine, collapse="\n"))` is one way to do this within R.

Comment: Unfortunately to my knowledge creating the string with sprintf  Julia_eval function within R causes an error. Furthermore, Combine is also not defined and causes errors on the Julia side. @ChrisRackauckas suggested compiling a large string but I am still trying to just have a variable placeholder be within the juliacall as opposed to copying and pasting the differential equations

Comment: Just wondering if anyone could let me know if it is even possible to assign a string to a variable which I call to be evaluate in juliaCall::julia_eval? I can't figure out how to interpolate the string into the string ($Combine? https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/strings/#string-interpolation-1). The reason I cant type out the differential expressions is that they change length depending on the situation I evaluate.

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas while the string I mentioned above does work, would there be a way to pass it all directly from R as an argument by using a closure within the original function? I.e, $Combine (which is equal to `"du[1] = - 1*0.4545*(u[1]^1) - 1*27000000*(u[4]^1)*(u[1]^1)\n ...`

Comment: Why are you trying to do any of this? I already mentioned it's slower. Don't do any of this stuff from Julia. There's no Julia involved in this question at all. It's really just a question of how to write a string in R. That would be better for performance, and it would be much simpler. Trying to pass a full Combine function from R to Julia and then ... that just doesn't even make sense. Please just do it the simpler and better way, and this can be done in a few minutes. @jverzani already answered it. I am trying to be nice here but I can't help you go down the wrong path.

Answer (score 0):

As @jverzani mentioned,

```
sprintf("function f(du,u,p,t)\n%s\nend", paste(Combine, collapse="\n"))
```

builds the string in R that you want. If you `JuliaCall::julia_eval` that, then you're done. Anything else is completely over-complicated, and will also be less optimized anyways, and so I would no recommend the other paths you are trying to take here.